# How to ping multiple hosts using SimplePing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, networking, ping

I'm using this SimplePing sample code by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html
to ping other hosts in the LAN.
I'm using this method:

```
+ (SimplePing *)simplePingWithHostAddress:(NSData *)hostAddress;
```

Works fine, but I want to ping multiple hosts at once. I just don't know how to do that.

I have a NSArray full of IPs (NSString). Can someone please give me an example?

Thx!

Comment: Just take a look through the sample code, identify how it does what it does and modify it so that it loops through multiple IPs. If you have a problem with a **specific** part of that then ask a **specific** question. We won't write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need a fast enumeration loop.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW28)

Comment: Yea, but I have to somehow create multiple SimplePing objects in order to ping every IP ... o_O

Comment: @Daniel: No, you don't. Look at the method you quoted: The `+` indicates that it is a class method. No instance of SimplePing is necessary; indeed, if there's no instance-method counterpart, creating an instance would do nothing for you.

Comment: Two-years-ago me was an idiot. Yes, you do need to create a SimplePing object for each address. Each one maintains a socket for that address, so that's the simplest way to keep track of which pings haven't come back yet.

Comment: Can you please update your answer since the link is not working? It would be helpful for guys likes us  who are facing the same problem :)

Comment: @PeterHosey im trying the same in swift 3. But not getting response. Any clue for swift version?

Comment: @PeterHosey Unfortunately Apple's SimplePing API is build on C libraries and it seems their callbacks won’t work with GCD, thus this has to run in main thread.  Is there anyway to Ping hosts on a background thread?

Comment: It should work on any thread; you'll get your callbacks on the same thread where you called -start. The catch is that this doesn't play well with GCD, which abstracts away threads and treats them as its own implementation detail, nor integrate with dispatch at all. To get responses dispatched to a queue, you'd need to either alter SimplePing to a GCD-based implementation yourself, or at least wrap it in an object of your own class that maintains a long-running NSThread and dispatches the responses as they come in.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<[self.hostArray count]; i++) 
{
[SimplePing simplePingWithHostAddress:[hostArray objectAtIndex:i]]; 
}
```

Comment: Does this actually works? Are you able to ping different IPAddress from Apple Simple Ping Library?

Comment: @creative_rd This indeed works, you need to keep references of Simple Ping object. But Unfortunately Apple's SimplePing API is build on C libraries and it seems their callbacks won’t work with GCD, thus this has to run in main thread. That is an issue.